# Using node mssql how do I create a database?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I tried the `execute` method:

```
const sql = require('../node_modules/mssql');
var dbname = 'AddressBook';
sql.connect('mssql://sa:1234@localhost/').then(pool => {
  return pool.request().input('db_name', sql.TYPES.Text, dbname).query`select db_id(@db_name) as idn`.then(result => {
    if (result[0].idn === null) {
      return pool.request().input('db_name', sql.TYPES.Text, dbname).execute`create database @db_name`;
    }
  }).catch(err => {throw(err)});
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I get:

> message: 'The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. The RPC name is invalid.',

Also tried the `query` method:

```
      return pool.request().input('db_name', sql.TYPES.Text, dbname).query`create database @db_name`;
```

I get

> message: 'Incorrect syntax near \'@db_name\'.',

Is there a different method or am I missing something?

Comment: this works `return pool.request().query(\`create database ${dbname}\`);` - I think you're overusing tagged templates :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you very much, it worked. But what's the difference between what I tried and yours?

Comment: firstly, `create database 'AddressBook'` (which is what your code would possibly try) is invalid, it's `create database AddressBook` (without the quotes) - secondly, the tagged template syntax makes the request something even less correct - I don't fully understand tagged templates, so I can't explain it

Comment: yep, removed the `'` from the "correct" version :p sorry, copy/paste laziness

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you